# Homebrew in Ubuntu getting uninstalled after reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, homebrew, brew

I am installing properly Homebrew in my ubuntu 22.04 and everything is fine brew doctor, brew --version everything is running properly. But everytime I am rebooting my system, the homebrew is getting uninstalled I dont know why this is happening. Please someone suggest a solution

Comment: Cross-posted: https://askubuntu.com/q/1441828/158442

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew does not uninstall itself. Your issue is probably the following:

```
$ brew --version
bash: brew: command not found
```

You can verify that it still exists as follows:

```
$ /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew --version
Homebrew 4.1.1
```

You can run `brew` without writing the full path by adding `"$(brew --prefix)"/bin` (`/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/`) in `PATH`. You can do so by running the `eval` command:

```
$ brew --version
bash: brew: command not found
$ eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
$ brew --version
Homebrew 4.1.1
```

The `eval` command can be found under "Next steps" when running the install script. If you are using `bash`, you may want to add the command to your `.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile` for login shells):

```
echo 'eval "$(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> .bashrc
```

---

Related:

StackOverflow: [Installing Homebrew on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381128/installing-homebrew-on-macos/66457878)

Homebrew (discussions): ["brew: command not found" after installation  #775](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/775)